# With C#/dot.NET, auto-validating new cell value on DataGridView when checking a cell

Tags: c#, checkbox, datatable, datagridview, click

I'm working on a project coded in C#/.NET.
I have a main form that open a new form when a click on a button.
In this new form, I have a DataGridView filled with a DataTable :

```
dataGridView_color_selection.DataSource = GLOBALS.ListDataTableColorSets[comboBox_color_sets.SelectedIndex];
```

My first column is a checkBox column.
When I check or uncheck a row, I want this to be updated in DataTable.
But after checked a row, I have to select another row to validate the previous change.
I want the DataTable upgraded each time I check or uncheck a cell in real time

I've tried to change some properties on DataGridView control but it doesn't have work.

I've tried to catch the event Click on DataGridView and directly upgrade DataTable with value of CheckBox cell. No result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Call `[DataGridView].EndEdit();` in the `CellContentClick` event handler (verify that the current Column is a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn) -- You could also call `Validate()`, but there's a (not so) slight difference when you do that. Test it

Comment: Yes !! Your solution has worked. I've call EndEdit() on a ContentClick event. Thanks a lot.